# Bootstrap grid squeeze link click area

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sprite

I do have the following structure in my bootstrap grid:

```
<!-- banner -->
<div class="banner">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-6">
              <div class="social-flag">
                <a href="#" class="linkedin"></a>
                <a href="#" class="twitter"></a>
                <a href="#" class="rss"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-6 profile-picture">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end banner -->
```

The div social-flag contains 3 links placed vertically with sprite background images.
When I resize my browser to mobile width the social-flag div and links becomes wider then col-xs-1, that is the result I want. But the problem is that my click-able area gets the width of col-xs-1. So it is hard to click those links on smaller screens.
How do I give my links full width click area?

Comment: Col-xs-12 is full-width.

Comment: Well profile-picture is left aligned on 11 columns, exactly how I want it graphically

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a little at your CSS but it sounds like applying a z-index higher than 0 to your first column will solve your issue. This will bring the first column above the profile-picture column.

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dw9ZB/

```
.flagcolumn {
   z-index:1;
}
```